# Kotlin FragmentStatePageAdapter destroy view on third swipe if it has more than 2 items

Tags: kotlin

I have set the FragmentStatePageAdapter to swipe through fragments of the same layout and different data (users profiles). 
When I give it list of 2 items all work well. 
If I give it 3 or more items it creates views for fragments, but on third swipe contents turn blank, regardless to which direction I swipe (forward then forward, forward then backward). If I accurately slide to third item when still holding the screen I can see it's valid contents, but when I finish slide releasing the screen all disappears.

Page Adapter is set like below. (swipeList is list of users' ids, swipeEntityType == 0, each User contents is loaded by "uid" passed through bundle)

```
class SwipePagerFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var parent: MainActivity
    private lateinit var state: State
    private lateinit var ctx: Context
    private lateinit var swipeList: MutableList<Int>
    private lateinit var pager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_swipe_pager, container, false)

        parent = activity as MainActivity
        state = parent.state
        ctx = state.ctx
        swipeList = state.swipeList

        pager = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentSwipePager_pager)
        val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        pager.adapter = pagerAdapter

        return view
    }

    private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        override fun getCount(): Int = swipeList.size

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = when (state.swipeEntityType) {
            0 -> {
                makeUserFragment(swipeList[position])
            }
            else -> {
                makeEventFragment(swipeList[position])
            }
        }
    }

    private fun makeUserFragment(uid: Int): UserFragment {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("uid", uid)
        val frag = UserFragment()
        frag.arguments = bundle
        return frag
    }

    private fun makeEventFragment(eid: Int): EventFragment {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("eid", eid)
        val frag = EventFragment()
        frag.arguments = bundle
        return frag
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
pager.offscreenPageLimit = swipeList.size
```

solves my problem